# Sequential Reference Numbers

Tags: t-sql, sequential

I have a table currently only two columns because I am learning, the first column is the Book_skey and this is generated automatically by the system using the IDENTITY function, however what I would like to do in the second coloumn is create a automated field called BookRef where the first row will be B00000001 the next row will be B00000002 etc.

```
USE Occupancy

DECLARE @BookNumber INT
SET @BookNumber = 1
WHILE @BookNumber <= 5000

BEGIN
INSERT INTO Book(BookNumber)
SELECT @BookNumber
SET @BookNumber = @BookNumber + 1

END
```

Can this be done?

Thanks

Wayne

Comment: What is the distinction between `Book_skey` and `BookRef`? Why do you need two identifiers? Is `BookRef` essentially just `B` + Book_skey padded out with trailing zeroes?

Comment: Hi Martin

The Book_Skey will be the system Idetifiers the BookRef will used for correspondence etc.

Comment: But why do you need to store it? Can't you just calculate it from `Book_skey`? `SELECT 'B' + RIGHT('0000000' + CAST(Book_skey AS VARCHAR(8)),8)`

Comment: I don't know to be honest Martin, I am new to SQL and I have been asked to populate a table and this is what I have been given.

Comment: `IDENTITY` is not guaranteed sequential though. That requirement should be avoided if possible for reasons of concurrency.

Comment: Hi Martin do you know if it possible to do with the two columns?

Comment: Thanks for you help Martin all sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use a computed column.

```
CREATE TABLE Book (
    Book_skey       int IDENTITY(1,1)
   ,BookRef         as ('B' + RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(9), (100000000 + BookNumber)),8))
   ,BookNumber      int
)

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @BookNumber INT
SET @BookNumber = 1
WHILE @BookNumber <= 5000
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Book(BookNumber)
    SELECT @BookNumber

    SET @BookNumber = @BookNumber + 1
END

SELECT * FROM Book
```